# Select rows from 3-d nd-array

Tags: numpy

the situation is as following: If I have a numpy array of shape (64, 100, 300) and I want to transform it to (64, 1, 300) based on an array of indices of shape 64, what should I do? Say we have

```
a=np.random.randn(64, 100, 300)
indices = np.random.randint(low=0, high=100, size=64)
```

I currently do

```
a[:, indices, :]
```

which does not work. The returning array is of shape (64, 64, 300) since it tries to select the series of values from every batch.

Comment: Use `a[np.arange(len(indices)), indices]`. Or `a[np.arange(len(indices)), indices,None]` for that singleton dim.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. But I am just curious why does letting the third dim to be ```None``` helps?

Comment: That None/np.newaxis just adds back a new axis that was lost by the advanced-indexing.

Comment: This is a standard `numpy` question, and it has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the comment above suggests:

```
a[np.arange(indices.size),indices,None]
```

Or equally but more readable:

```
a[np.arange(indices.size),indices][:,None,:]
```